# How do I generate more than one dom element from a react.rb component

Tags: reactjs, opal, react.rb

I am trying to get the following code working:

```
class HelloWorld < React::Component::Base
  # stuff
  def render
    div { "hello" }
    div { "goodby" }
  end
end
```

but I keep getting this error:

`Exception raised while rendering #<HelloWorld:0x489>
    RuntimeError: a components render method must generate and return exactly 1 element or a string`

Answer (score 2):

React.rb components (like react.js) can only render a single root dom element.

To generate multiple elements you need to wrap the elements in a div, for example:

```
class HelloWorld < React::Component::Base
  # stuff
  def render
    div do
      div { "hello" }
      div { "goodby" }
    end
  end
end
```